# Android - How to Use a certain class in Main class?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

   Private TextView textView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
   }
}
```

**SecondActivity.class**

```
public class SecondActivity{

   private String name=""mName;
   private int x=1;
   private int y=2;
   private int z;

   public void add(){
   z=x+y;
   }
}
```

**my question is how to set the text of the textView in the main activity by the values of a string that contains (name & z) ?**

Comment: copy the code of operation class.

Comment: post your complete code

Comment: sorry it's my first time to post a question :)

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow then. You should edit your question to provide some context :
- Why are there *two* activities ?
- In which activity is the textView ?
- In which activity do you want to change it ?

It may also help to precise what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume that you have a String in Operation.class that has some value in it which you want to assign to the Text view in MainActivity. Make sure that variable is public.

```
public String text1 = "this is text for textview";
```

Now the string above is in Operations.class and you can access the value of variable text that is declared in Operations.class from MainActivity.java like this

```
Operations obj = new Operations();
            String text = obj.text;
```

Then assign it to the text view like this

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_text_view);
    textView.setText(text);
```

You can do same thing with functions and this is one of the fundamentals of programming so I suggest you look into it.

> For the simple add function in your case

First of all declare your function with a return type so when you access it you get a value back. I'm going to redefine your function

```
public int add()
    {
        z = x + y;
        return z;
    }
```

now when you call the function from your mainactivity like this

```
Operations obj = new Operations();
            Int value = obj.add();
```

It will store the value of z inside the variable value. Now if you want to set the text for textView by combining both value and text1 from before you have to first convert the value toString and then you can simply concatenate them in a 3rd variable and use that variable in setText().

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If not then I can provide you full solution.

Comment: I tried declaring a string with a value in the second class and called it in main activity as you explained and it worked .. my problem now is my second activity got many functions and variables it can be solved if I copy the code in my main but is there a way to compile the java code in the second class when main starts as if it is written in it ?

Comment: I'm gonna edit the answer above to show you how you can access a function take a look.

Comment: tyvm you really helped me :)